# Binary executable won't launch if called outside of source folder

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, launcher

I am trying to launch the 32-bit binary `reclient_linux_32` that comes with the Linux Red Eclipse game. I've successfully built from source and also have another version of the executable. If I open a window and manually click on either executable, then the game launches without problem. If I open a terminal, navigate to the folder where either binary is located, and execute it from command line, then both also launch with no problem.

But if I make an app launcher, or even just open a terminal and execute the command to launch the binary from some different directory, I get an error saying that the game cannot load textures. I'm assuming these texture files are located locally near the binary files. But still, many executables require nearby files yet can still be launched from anywhere. Why is this an issue?

Please note: both executables have correct permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "game" probably has hard-coded paths to directories relative to the working directory.  i.e. "../textures/blah"  instead of "/usr/local/game/textures/blah" ... without the src... couldn't begin to test.

Comment: You're probably correct, but it is a well-maintained game: [link](http://www.redeclipse.net/). If they did hard-code file paths, is there no work around that launches the binary as though it was being launched from within that folder? Could I make a script that simulates navigating there, then executing it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that the program is searching the textures files only in the current directory (the message says so). To get closer to the reason, your could run the program with `strace -v /path/to/program`, it should show you what files it wants to open.